# Sharing MS Access dB for multi user edit

Tags: nas, webserver, microsoft-access

I need to share a MS Access database file between multiple PCs so they would be able to edit and view the other's edits in realtime.

I have no server to make a NAS and Windows File-Sharing service isn't good here either. Is there any free solution for that? Even a free SQL database (like FireBase but without limitations).

---

What I have tried so far + conclutions:

Google Drive Desktop - it shows up as a local drive, though it's no good cause it basically uploads the latest of the edited file.

RaiDrive - simulates any cloud service as a local drive, meaning it doesn't download the file on the PC edits it and reuploads, it edits it directly from the cloud. I tried connecting to Google Drive using this and it worked as needed, though it is incredibly slow to the point it not usable (for some reason it makes the C# app that uses the database slow as well, perhaps because of the way I wrote to sync for changes in database).

ProFreeHost - they provide a free server with a free domain and unlimited traffic, disk space and SQL database. Problem is the SQL database is limited to be used withing the server only in the free plan. I tried connecting to the server with FTP, the application showed up with the data inside the MS Access database but it couldn't write to it (I guess they have thought of that and thus limited file editing outside of the server, only thing you can do is upload and delete files from the server).

Any other solution to the problem? Thanks in advance for everyone!

Comment: Why do you need to do that? On how many computers? Are any other similar programs also suitable (e.g. MEGA)

Comment: I need to have a shared drive between multiple PCs so they would work on the same MS Access file through a C# application. If MEGA allows multi user accessing the same file at the same time so no problem using that.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446

Comment: I am familiar with these options in the link, but it’s not suitable for me. I have no server (otherwise I would use MS Access as database), and PCs might be outside of local network. Thus I wanted a file sharing service such as Google Drive or OneDrive.

Comment: https://599cd.com/blog/display-article.asp?ID=2234 "In this video, I will explain why you should not use file sharing services such as OneDrive, Google Drive, or DropBox to run your Microsoft Access databases with multiple simultaneous users. You will end up with missing data at best, and a corrupted database at worst."

Comment: I have also seen that video while I was looking for a solution, but after some testing I've done it has prooved as working just fine. I also do a backup to the database every shutdown of the application to have a safety net. Moreover, right now it's the only solution I've got (a free one, unless you know something better I am open to suggestions).

Comment: https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=onedrive-dropbox-offline-folder-access-database

Comment: Alright then. Any solution? Maybe I can mount Heroku as a local disk or something, I really don't need much of memory, just the sharing of the MS Access file.

Comment: How about you rewrite the question. Here in the comments you've gone a long way from "I need to install Google Drive unattended and silently and without an active user session". Write this question to be about the root issue you're trying to solve rather than how you thought you'd solve it the first time.

Comment: What are the requirements? Does it need to be free? How big is the db in gb? How many concurrent users?

Comment: @music2myear You are right, it really came to my mind. I changed it, thanks!

Comment: @Gantendo Does the rephrased question answers? database doesn't need to be big, I can also perform a backup to local disk if needed cause of low space. It needs to be free. Most of the time less than 5 users concurrent.

Comment: @WillingMost7 Thank you, much better! Years ago I had a somewhat similar problem, and the person I was helping had a very tight budget. We ended up using a second-hand raspberry pi which ended up costing (IIRC) about 15-20 euros and 5 euro's in energy consumption per year. I haven't tried it but you may want to take a look at https://free.caspio.com/ and figure out if the limits are acceptable for your application.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, I'll vote it back up.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really leaned towards buying a Raspberry Pi, it came to mind along the tests I ran. It is my last resort I guess. The Caspio option is interesting, though it requires me to rewrite my whole C# application to the Caspio platform which in that case I would already use ProFreeHost for better customization and less limitations. Thanks a lot!! I appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: Try using the free tier on AWS?  *Using Amazon EC2 Microsoft Windows Server Micro Instances*  aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier-faqs/

Comment: @user59748 truly brilliant, don't know how I didn't come up with this myself especially when I was using their service a bit lately. Yet it is for a limited time and I have already impelemted this with the Raspberry Pi. Thanks a lot!